# show two surface area formulas are equivalent

Tags: geometry, derivation-of-formulae

[image]

According to Wikipedia, for a uniform n-gonal antiprism with edge length $a$, SA = $\frac{n}{2} \left( \cot\frac{\pi}{n} + \sqrt{3} \right) a^2$ .  This formula seems unnecessarily complex to me, as I deduced the surface area should just be the area of each base plus the areas of the 2n equilateral triangles, which means the formula should be SA = 2B + 2n$\Bigl(\!\frac{a^2\sqrt{3}}{4}\Bigr)$.  Can anyone show these formulas are equivalent?  (Pictures are always appreciated.)  I'm also wondering whether there is a specific reason to use the first formula rather than the second.

Comment: What's your formula for $B$? ... Since you've mentioned that the area is the two bases, plus those triangles, you *could* say that the area is simply $2B+2nT$ (with $B$ the base area and $T$ the triangle area). But that's not terribly helpful. The reason to use the first formula —and, presumably, the reason you incorporated the formula for $T$ in the second— is because it expresses the full area in terms of just $n$ and the side-length $a$.

Comment: ^Depends on which type of regular polygon forms the base of a given antiprism.

Comment: *"Depends on which type of regular polygon..."* Correct, which means that just calling it $B$ leaves more work for the reader. By incorporating the formula for $B$, the first formula isn't *unnecessarily* complex; it's as complex as needed to be fully informative. (BTW: "^" isn't useful here, since comments can be presented out of order. If you're wanting to direct a comment at someone (and ensure that the someone gets a notification of that comment), use @name .) Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, you have figured out the areas of the triangles: That's your $2n(a^2\frac{\sqrt{3}}4)$. However, the area of the base is not always immediately clear. Imagine if I have an octagon for example, we should have a formula for calculating the base area!

We do that by splitting the base into n equal isosceles triangles. At the centre, obviously the angle will be $\frac{2\pi}{n}$, and the outer side will be a! So using the cosine rule, we can find the length of the inner sides of the triangle to be $\frac{a}{2*sin(pi/n)}$. Using the formula for the area of a triangle, we get each triangle has an area of $\frac{a^2cot(\frac{\pi}{n})}{4}$ Now there are n many of these triangles on each base, and two base sides, so multiply that by 2n to get to that required area!

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you so much :-)